# R- gsub Doesn't Replace Text

Tags: r, gsub

I'm afraid this is my first go at R and scraping so bear with me.

I'm trying to scrape price data off of a website and can't seem to clean away the non-essential characters to be left with just the numbers.

Any advice greatfully received!

```
#Specifying the url for the website
url <- 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-4/Wohnung-Kauf/Berlin/Berlin/-/1,00-'

#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

#Using CSS selectors to scrap the rankings section
price_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.result-list-entry__primary-criterion:nth-child(1)')

#Converting the ranking data to text
price_data <- html_text(price_data_html)

#Data-Preprocessing: removing non-numbers 
price_data<-gsub("\n","",price_data)


price_data<-gsub(" €                                                                                                                Kaufpreis                                    ",
                 "",price_data)

price_data<-gsub("                                                        ","",price_data)

price_data<-gsub(" €Kaufpreis                                    ","",price_data)

#Reviewing the data
head(price_data)
```

Comment: Are you looking to extract just the numbers from your scrapped text? You should try `price_data1 <- str_extract(price_data,"[\\d.]+")` after `html_text()`

Comment: That doesn't seem to change the result at all, I just end up with the very long string of text including "\n" 's.

Comment: That's strange! I ran your code as it is with minor modification at the end - `library(rvest);
url <- 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-4/Wohnung-Kauf/Berlin/Berlin/-/1,00-';
webpage <- read_html(url);
price_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.result-list-entry__primary-criterion:nth-child(1)');
price_data <- html_text(price_data_html);
price_data1<-str_extract(price_data,"[\\d.]+");
head(price_data1)`. The result is `[1] "1.557"  "36.500" "49.700" "50.500" "51.300" "52.100"`

Comment: It's a very neat code but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work. I must be doing something wrong but not sure what it could be.

Comment: Maybe you should run `rm(list=ls())` before trying with my suggested code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDIT: Based on comments, modified the code. The issue probably lies in
>   the encodig of the string.

```
#Data-Preprocessing: removing non-numbers 
price_data<-gsub("\n","",price_data)
price_data<-gsub("Kaufpreis","",price_data)
price_data<-gsub(" ","",price_data)
price_data = gsub("[^[:alnum:].]", "", price_data)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's very helpful but hasn't seemed to solve the problem entirely. If I amend the gsub to the following, it looks better but still can't get rid of the "€Kaufpreis" for some reason... 

price_data<-gsub("\n","",price_data)
price_data<-gsub(" ","",price_data)
price_data<-gsub("€Kaufpreis","",price_data)

which gives me the following result:

  "1.557€Kaufpreis"  "36.500€Kaufpreis" "49.700€Kaufpreis" "50.500€Kaufpreis" "51.300€Kaufpreis"
[6] "52.100€Kaufpreis"

Comment: For me this works fine, I am left with just numbers. What errors or unexpected output do you get when applying my code? EDIT: I see your comment was edited, I'll take a look.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the encoding of the string. I modified my answer to only keep the alphanumeric characters and the dot at the end. Could you try and see if this works for you?

Comment: That works! Thank you very much. If you have the time could you explain what that last line does?

Comment: Great, glad I could help. The last line uses an expression that says that all characters that are not alphanumeric [:alnum:], or are not a dot (.), will be replaced with "". Some more info can be found here: http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php. Would you be so kind to accept my answer? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. Of course, just as soon as I find aout how to do that...